# Ошибка при запуске программы после публикации vb.net

Tags: .net, visual-basic

Программируем в vb.net, фреймворк 4. Публикуем программу на общем сервере компании.

Вроде все работает, но у человека не запускается программа, пишет вот такую ошибку:

```
CLR20r3
01: dfsvc.exe
02: 4.0.30319.1
03: 4ba1e198
04: System.Windows.Forms
05: 4.0.0.0
06: 54d9ba30
07: 13bf
```

и т.д.

Насколько я понимаю, сам dfsvc контролирует фоновое обновление. Фреймворк у пользователя есть, почему может возникать проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Были ошибки в реестре так как пользователь работал в восьмерке на Линуксе. Переустановил фреймворки и поправил реестр - все заработало.

Comment: Ничего не понял.